# nose test freezing at raw_input

Tags: python, nose, nosetests, raw-input

I have a nose test that imports a file which runs a class with raw_inputs. Whenever I type nosetests in the command line, the prompt simply pauses and doesn't continue - I have to keyboard interrupt to see what happens, and it turns out the nose test is running my file up to the first raw_input (one of many), at which point it simply pauses and cannot continue.

Any way to bypass this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, rewrite the file so it won't call raw_input() when imported.

```
# imported file
if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_input()
```

Otherwise, if you can figure out in advance what would be acceptable input, you can take standard input from a file. Assuming input.txt contains "Pass":

```
nosetests test_input.py < input.txt
```

where test_input.py is:

```
# test file
def test_input():
    s = raw_input()
    assert s.strip() == "Pass"
```

Or you can pipe acceptable input into nosetests:

```
c:\>echo Pass | nosetests test_input.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
OK

c:\>echo Fail | nosetests test_input.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: cgp.test.test_input.test_input
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 187, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "c:\test_input.py", line 3, in test_input
    assert s.strip() == "Pass"
AssertionError
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s
FAILED (failures=1)
```